# RegisterCallback<T>(Action<T> func) , how do I store this function pointer in a class?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action, func

I'm trying to expose an API such that, I do the following

```
RegisterCallback<T>(Action<T> func)
{
    someObj.FuncPointer = func;
}
```

Later on, I call func(obj) .. and the obj is of type T that the user said.

More concrete example:

```
var callbackRegistrar = new CBRegistrar();
callbackRegistrar.RegisterCallback<ISomeClass>(SomeFunc);

public static void SomeFunc(ISomeClass data)
{
    //
}
```

**EDIT**: So I may not have been clear, so I'll add more code:

I want to make only "one" object of CBRegistrar, and connect it with many Callbacks, as such:

```
var callbackRegistrar = new CBRegistrar();
callbackRegistrar.RegisterCallback<ISomeClass>(SomeFunc);
callbackRegistrar.RegisterCallback<ISomeOtherClass>(SomeFunc2);
...
```

In fact the above code is called by reflecting over a directory of plugins.

The user puts this in their code -->

```
public static void SomeFunc(ISomeClass data)
{
    //
}

public static void SumFunc2(ISomeOtherClass data)
{
    //
}
```

It looks to me as if this is not possible using Generics, etc. What it looks like I might have to do is make an interface called IPlugin or something, and ask the user to do this ..

```
[PluginIdentifier(typeof(ISomeClass))]
public static void SomeFunc(IPluginData data)
{
    var castedStuff = data as ISomeClass; // ISomeClass inherits from IPluginData
}
```

Seems like asking the user to do stuff that we should take care of, but anyway ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Action<T> func` to store it in. There is a semantic check to make here: if someone calls `RegisterCallback` *twice* (with different values), do you want to *replace* the callback, or *keep both* ? Assuming the latter, `someObj` probably wants an `event` (indeed, this entire API could be exposed as an event), so - in the `someObj` class:

```
public event Action<T> FuncPointer;
private void InvokeCallback(T data) {
    var handler = FuncPointer;
    if(handler != null) handler(data);
}
```

Noting that `RegisterCallback` could be replaced entirely, still keeping the data on `obj`:

```
public event Action<T> Completed {
    add { obj.FuncPointer += value; }
    remove { obj.FuncPointer -= value; }
}
```

Then usage would be:

```
var callbackRegistrar = new CBRegistrar();
callbackRegistrar.Completed += SomeFunc;
```

Comment: The problem with your last usage is that it couples CBRegistrar with Completed. Moreover, now there is a finite list of events that can be used. I'm essentially reading a directory of plugins and dynamically hooking these callbacks.

Comment: Yeah, I need an Action<T> .. but that just gives a compilation error, understandly so, coz it doesn't know the type. I'm beating my head around this ... Action<T> doesn't compile, coz there is no T in the "someobj" class ..

Answer (score 0):

Callback functions are not much used in C#. They've been replaced by [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which are more elegant and easier to work with.

```
class CBRegistrar
{
    public delegate void ActionRequiredEventHandler(object sender, ISomeClass e); 

    public event ActionRequiredEventHandler ActionRequired;
    void RaiseActionRequiredEvent(ISomeClass parm)
    {
       if ( ActionRequired != null)
       {
           ActionRequired(this, parm);
       }
    }

}

class APIConsumer
{
     var callbackRegistrar = new CBRegistrar();
     public APIConsumer()
     {

               callbackRegistrar.ActionRequired += SomeFunc;


     }
     public void SomeFunc(object sender, ISomeClass data)
     {

     }

}
```

If you still want to use Callbacks, you can use [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which are more or less function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The CBRegistrar will need to be generic (if it's OK to keep a single callback type) or it can do some internal casting (if several callback types need to be registered).

```
public class CBRegistrar<T>
{
    private Action<T> callback;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> callbackMap;

    public CBRegistrar()
    {
        this.callbackMap = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public void RegisterCallback(Action<T> func)
    {
        this.callback = func;
    }

    public void RegisterGenericCallback<U>(Action<U> func)
    {
        this.callbackMap[typeof(U)] = func;
    }

    public Action<U> GetCallback<U>()
    {
        return this.callbackMap[typeof(U)] as Action<U>;
    }
}

public interface ISomeClass
{
    string GetName();
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var callbackRegistrar = new CBRegistrar<ISomeClass>();

            callbackRegistrar.RegisterCallback(SomeFunc);
            callbackRegistrar.RegisterGenericCallback<ISomeClass>(SomeFunc);

            var someone = new SomeClass();

            callbackRegistrar.GetCallback<ISomeClass>()(someone);
        }

        public static void SomeFunc(ISomeClass data)
        {
            // Do something
            Console.WriteLine(data.GetName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... it looks like I'll have to have an interface and just tell my API consumers to adorn it with an attribute or something to convey the info to me ... sigh.